# How do you upgrade Apache POI in Lucee 5.3.10.97 from 2.5.1 to 3.17?

Tags: iis, apache-poi, windows-server-2016, lucee

I manage a Windows Server 2016 that has Lucee 5.3.10.97 with IIS, and bundled within Lucee is Apache POI 2.5.1.  I have requirements to update this to at least Apache POI 3.17.  Can I just drop a newer JAR of poi 3.17 over the 2.5.1 bundled in Lucee, or am I unable to do so because this jar is referenced somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand it, Lucee doesn't include POI in its core any longer. The older version you are seeing is probably the one bundled with the Tika library.

The simplest way of using a more recent version of POI is to install the POI Lucee Extension which has POI 5.0.0. Look for it in the `Extension > Applications` section of the Lucee server admin UI (click the "Pre Releases" button if you don't see it). Or you can download the .lex file from https://download.lucee.org/ (scroll down for extensions) and drop it in your `lucee-server/deploy` folder.

As Lucee uses OSGi, the different versions won't interfere with each other.

Comment: Thanks for the comment about it being bundled with Tika.  Do you see any harm in just deleting the old existing org.apache.poi-2.5.1.jar file?

Comment: Actually it is part of the Lucene Search Engine.  I uninstalled that extension, and the jar was removed.